# why listview getcount() is equal to zero?

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, count

I have a problem with counting the number of items in ListView.
I'm pushing values into a folder in the firebase database. When I pull them on a separate activity, I get a list of the values I pushed .
The problem is I want to know how many items the list has. I tried to use listView.getCount() and also with arrayList.size() and both show zero, even though in the list itself I do see the values. Why is it happening ?

Here is my Java code:

```
     list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewId2);
        check2 = findViewById(R.id.check3);

        arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        keyList = new ArrayList<String>();
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(recommendations_weight.this ,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList);
        list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


        mDatabaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Recommendations").child("Blood").child("WBC").child("High").child("Weight").child("1");


        mDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                arrayList.add(value); // include the scan values
                keyList.add(dataSnapshot.getKey()); //include the id of each tests
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


//check if we have item
    if (list.getAdapter().getCount() != 0){
        check2.setText("number");
    }
```

and this is my xml -

```
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewId2"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:visibility="visible"

        android:textAlignment="center" />




    <Button
        android:id="@+id/returnButton"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="return to test page"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:background="#60000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/check3"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="check"
        />
```

Comment: What does you adapter class look like?

Comment: The code is very unclear, could you upload the code to github and send the link?
Also try to call the method directly on the arrayAdapter itself. Not on the list.

Answer (score 0):

One simply cannot expect the `ArrayAdapter` to be already populated, when entering asynchronous execution and then instantly checking in a synchronous manner, if there are any items contained.

As your code currently works (or better said: won't work):

- at first, it requests remote data (entering asynchronous execution).
- then it instantly checks the item-count in the adapter (synchronous execution).
- then the items are being added (asynchronous execution).
- asynchronous execution finishes.

Asynchronous execution requires callbacks, else you won't know when it had finished.

Just add verbose logging, in order to understand what is going on and *in which order*.

Answer (score -1):

You're getting 0 because you are checking `list.getAdapter().getCount()`. I think you want to check whatever list variable holds the data you pass in (I doubt it's `adapter`).

So maybe: `list.getAdapter.getArrayList().getCount()`?

Comment: I would like to check how many organs I have in ArrayList \ Listview. I tried using what you suggested but I get an error in the getArrayList command. There is no such command in the Adapter class at Andoroid Studio./ tanks

Comment: Doesn't surprise me. I don't know what you adapter class looks like, which is why I asked for the code and said "maybe". You need to access the list in your adapter, whatever that is.

Comment: I did not create my own ArrayAdapter class. I just created an arrayAdapter user that connected me between the listView and ArrayList. What's needed to be add to internal class of
Adapter?
Why do I manage to access to specific values in the list using the ArrayAdapter I'm currently using and can't use it to count the number of values in the list? If I will write a new adapter class of my own, what do I need for the new class of the ArrayAdapter to contain?